# How to extract xy coordinates to featuretable using ArcGIS web map/app to create points?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-online, geoprocessing-service

I have an ArcGIS online web app to collect points using the services served on our server. The featurelayer exists in our SDE server.  How can I extract and update the xy (lat/long) coordinates without having a task scheduled to run?

Comment: Are you wanting to pull the lat/lon data via the web application, or from the server side via a script or software?

Comment: the wep app..I have set up a python scrip to run, but rather not use it.